# Android accessing files by uri results with SecurityExcepption

Tags: android, android-storage, android-securityexception

I´m stuck with an security exception. I save audio file in my app and can play it. It works fine until device reboot. After reboot the app the trouble begins.

What I try to do is just start a media player which is created from URI. Here is how I do it:
First I create ForegroundService which is created like:

```
Intent sceneService = new Intent(context, SceneManager.class);
sceneService.putExtra("file", mFile);
context.startForegroundService(sceneService);
```

Then the service starts the media player class to start the audio file

```
public class SceneManager extends Service
{
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
       GameAudioPlayer player = GameAudioPlayer.getInstance();
       player.startScene(this, audio)
    }
}
```

The GameAudioPlayer does stuff:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(mFile.getUri()));
player.start()
```

And the result is:

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Music/my/path/to/file.mp3
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{2b6811f 18501:com.wintermute.adventuresmaster/u0a351} (pid=18501, uid=10351) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:5156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6807)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2762)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2163)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1689)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1521)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1438)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1127)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1099)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1011)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:918)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:895)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:874)
        at com.wintermute.adventuresmaster.services.player.GameAudioPlayer.preparePlayer(GameAudioPlayer.java:115)
        at com.wintermute.adventuresmaster.services.player.GameAudioPlayer.lambda$playScene$1$GameAudioPlayer(GameAudioPlayer.java:99)
        at com.wintermute.adventuresmaster.services.player.-$$Lambda$GameAudioPlayer$nydFlOv8edPL3wGxNrMmFC7swLI.accept(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1262)
        at com.wintermute.adventuresmaster.services.player.GameAudioPlayer.playScene(GameAudioPlayer.java:99)
        at com.wintermute.adventuresmaster.services.player.SceneManager.onStartCommand(SceneManager.java:84)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4204)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:231)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1984)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:7700)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerService.java:8028)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2127)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3015)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1032)
E/MediaPlayerNative: Unable to create media player
```

Comment: I see no service. Its an intent which you named service. I do not even understand that you can call startForegroundService on it. What happens if you do? What does it have to do with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT? Better use new Intent() to avoid confusion. Tell the value of `file' that you put extra. Is it a string or a File object?

Comment: SceneManager.class is extended from Service?

Comment: I didn´t paste the Service class here since it is not of meaning. I simplified the parts to important things. SceneManager extends Service and the 'file' is an POJO. The service gets file and extracts the uri of this object.

Comment: I did not ask to paste the service class. Please give the info i asked for. You cleared nothing. Tell the value of the used File or String or Uri. We cannot help you if you dont come to the point. POJO does not tell anything. Adapt your intent code so we see how you tell the service about your file. Which file?

Comment: `Uri.parse(file.getUri())` So does file.getUri() deliver a String and not an Uri? Maybe a content scheme?  Then tell the value. All starts with  the right path/uri/content scheme for your file.

Comment: You could also tell the value of Uri.parse(file.getUri()).toString().

Comment: Ok, sorry. I missunderstood you. I will edit the post asap. Short info. The uri is type of Uri, it´s not a String. First the String is obtained with android Storage Access Framework and looks like this: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Music/my/path/to/file.mp3. Then the app will parse the String to Uri and store it within the POJO file as Uri fileUri;

Comment: But I think, I found the core of the problem. It might be the flags and obtaining persistent permissions for the URI. I guess the problem comes when the Uri permissions are gone with reboot of the device, once the app try to get the file by uri, there are no permissions on it. I need to figure out how correctly set the flag to grant persistable uri permissions and then takePersistableUriPermission()

Comment: That is not as it goes. And you are pretty reluctant to give asked info i see.

Comment: I don´t know what you gonna do with that, but this is the uri value: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AMusic%2Frpg%2Fcyberpunk_example%2Flol2%2FtestMe%2FtestMeToo%2FMichael%20Giacchino%20-%20Jedha%20City%20Ambush%20(From%20Rogue%20One_%20A%20Star%20Wars%20St.mp3

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will study it. Tell also with which intent you obtained that content scheme.

Comment: You changed your intent code. Fine. But there is still ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Why? Makes no sense i think. How is that used in the service class? I asked that before. Still no answer. And setting that flag does nothing either.